# How to write Logic for given output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a logic for given input and I need desired output in JavaScript.

Given Input:

```
var test = [{parentId:1,subId:1,subSubId:1},
{parentId:1,subId:2,subSubId:null},
{parentId:1,subId:null,subSubId:null},
{parentId:2,subId:1,subSubId:1},
{parentId:2,subId:null,subSubId:null}];
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "category": [
    {
      "parentId": 1,
      "subCatgory": [
        {
          "subId": 1,
          "subSubCategory": [
            {
              "subSubId": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "subId": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parentId": 2,
      "subCatgory": [
        {
          "subId": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code that produces the current result?

Comment: I think what @technophyle is trying to say is we need to see an attempt at solving the problem. "but with no luck so far" is not good enough. This is not a code writing service. What did you try? What exactly went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This code can perform that:

```js
const test = [{
    parentId: 1,
    subId: 1,
    subSubId: 1
  },
  {
    parentId: 1,
    subId: 2,
    subSubId: null
  },
  {
    parentId: 1,
    subId: null,
    subSubId: null
  },
  {
    parentId: 2,
    subId: 1,
    subSubId: 1
  },
  {
    parentId: 2,
    subId: null,
    subSubId: null
  }
];

const parse = (data) => {
  const category = data.reduce((acc, { parentId, subId, subSubId }) => {
    let parent = acc.find(v => v.parentId === parentId)
    if (!parent) {
      parent = { parentId, subCategory: [] }
      acc.push(parent)
    }

    if (!subId) return acc
    let subCatetogy = parent.subCategory.find(v => v.subId === subId)
    if (!subCatetogy) {
      subCatetogy = { subId }
      parent.subCategory.push(subCatetogy)
    }
    
    if (!subSubId) return acc
    subCatetogy.subSubCategory = subCatetogy.subSubCategory || []
    subCatetogy.subSubCategory.push({ subSubId })
    return acc
  }, [])
  return { category }
}

console.log(parse(test))
```

Note: it seems like you've misspelled `subCatgory` so I've changed it to `subCategory`. And also `parentId: 2` has `subSubId: 1` in my solution, although it's in your test variable, but it seems missing in your desirable result.

Hope you find my answer useful :)

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you need to do. It also works when `subId` and `subSubId` are both `null`. Please check:

```js
const testData = [
  {
    parentId: 1,
    subId: 1,
    subSubId: 1
  },
  {
    parentId: 1,
    subId: 2,
    subSubId: null
  },
  {
    parentId: 1,
    subId: null,
    subSubId: null
  },
  {
    parentId: 2,
    subId: 1,
    subSubId: 1
  },
  {
    parentId: 2,
    subId: null,
    subSubId: null
  },
  {
    parentId: 3,
    subId: null,
    subSubId: null,
  }
];

function generateData(data) {
  /**
   * This will generate a map of objects that looks like this:
   *  map = {
   *    // parentId
   *    1: {
   *      // subId
   *      1: [
   *        // subSubId
   *        1,
   *        2,
   *        ...
   *      ],
   *      ...
   *    },
   *    ...
   *  }
   */
  const map = data.reduce((result, { parentId, subId, subSubId }) => {
    if (result[parentId]) {
      if (!subId) return result;
      if (result[parentId][subId]) {
        if (!subSubId) return result;
        result[parentId][subId].push(subSubId);
      } else {
        result[parentId][subId] = subSubId ? [subSubId] : [];
      }
    } else {
      if (subId) {
        result[parentId] = { [subId]: subSubId ? [subSubId] : [] };
      } else {
        result[parentId] = {};
      }
    }
    return result;
  }, {});

  const categories = Object.keys(map).map(parentId => {
    const parent = map[parentId];
    const category = { parentId };
    const subCategories = Object.keys(parent).map(subId => {
      const subSubs = parent[subId];
      const subCategory = { subId };
      if (subSubs.length) {
        subCategory.subSubCategory = subSubs.map(subSubId => ({ subSubId }));
      }
      return subCategory;
    });
    if (subCategories.length) {
      category.subCategory = subCategories;
    }
    return category;
  });

  return { category: categories };
}

const result = generateData(testData);
console.log(result);
```

I added some comments so you can understand it easily, but it would take a bit of time to fully understand the logic.